# Can I export a Power BI dashboard to Data Studio?

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, looker-studio

I have a dash made with Power BI, but I'm using Linux now and can't use it. I'd like to start using Data Studio, but I need to use the dashes I've already created with Power BI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your PowerBI dash from Linux, you just need to publish the dash to the PowerBI service after which you access it through a modern browser (e.g. Chrome). [See the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-upload-desktop-files).

In terms of getting your data out of PowerBI Desktop (thick client), there is no automated way. The best you can to is to create a PowerBI dash with a table visual and then include all relevant columns and rows to export in the table. Use the PowerBI export data feature to dump out to Excel. The same technique works in PowerBI service (the web version after you hace published). [See the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-export).

If you want to try get to your PowerBI service (published data) from an API, that is not possible in any general format. The only option comes with the Premium version of PowerBI where you can connect to an [XMLA endpoint to access the data](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-open-platform-connectivity-with-xmla-endpoints-public-preview/). Typically organisations do their data wrangling in a tool before passing the data on to PowerBI To avoid the lack of open connectivity (to the processed data in PowerBI).